# Import Azure V12 database to local SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, azure

While trying to import .bacpac file getting an error
"The compatibility level of the source schema is not supported"
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V12 from Azure requires SQL 2014 or later.  Otherwise, you're doing it correctly (bacpacs are fine, it's just the local SQL compatibility that's your problem)

Comment: thanks, thought that might be the case.. imported database using generate scripts instead.

Comment: Any approach to support this?